# Page header required on exported file excel or pdf

Tags: grails, plugins, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf, jasper-plugin

I have a web application and i need to export a list to a .xlsx or .pdf format. During exporting the page, page should contain the page header of the company along with the list. How is it possible? I am doing this project in grails. Is there any plugin which would make this possible. I've already tried Export Plugin in Grails, it does not have that facility.

Answer (score 0):

we are currently creating some exports to PDF with Grails. The reports contain also tables and different logos in the header.

We are using the itext library which fits pretty good our requirements. You have to be aware that the newer itext versions are not open source.

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4)

    def baos= new ByteArrayOutputStream(30)
    def dos= new DataOutputStream(baos)
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, dos)

    PageNumberEventHelper events = new PageNumberEventHelper()
    writer.setBoxSize("art", new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788))
    writer.setPageEvent(events);

    Font titleFont = new Font(Font.UNDEFINED, 22, Font.BOLD)

    document.open()
    // render title
    document.addTitle(getMessage('pricelist.title', [(new Date()).format('dd.MM.yyyy')]));
    document.add(new Paragraph(getMessage('pricelist.title', [(new Date()).format('dd.MM.yyyy')]), titleFont))
    document.add(new Paragraph(' '))

    ...

    document.close()
```

Comment: As far as I know the latest open source version is itext-2.1.7.jar.

Answer (score 0):

try [jasper plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jasper), you can make you own style output